# Height, percentages, animate issues

Tags: jquery, height, percentage

Well I have this: http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/HfqBy

OK, I've used animate(); before and it has worked perfectly. I just don't know why it doesn't this time.(It's a long image that I want to move on hover)

Also, I'm trying to make it responsive using percentages but It won't get any height if I don't use pixels.

Can you guys help me with that?
Thanks in advance!
Best regards!

Comment: Thanks Stano!, that works perfectly.

This is the attempt to make it responsive: http://jsfiddle.net/W6hCp/1/

I tried making body and html 100% width and height but still nothing

Comment: I did the same here, and it works, I'm not sure why though lol. It's still in progress:
 
http://mvalerio85.herzingwebdesign.com/port/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to solve it Stano.
I had tried that jquery solution before but it's not 100% responsive. I mean it resizes the box when the page loads, but if you resize it the height stays the same. In the page I posted I think it's working because the image is perfectly square.

Comment: That was perfect!. Stano, again, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had success by adjusting the way you are selecting elements.

Instead of using `children()` like this:

```
$(this).children('.frame img')
```

Try this, selecting `.frame img` within `this`.

```
$('.frame img',this)
```

http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/pfHLg

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I'm still learning this...I hope to get there eventually lol.

Comment: No problem. Yes, it takes some practice. I use this documentation quite a bit for help with tree-traversal: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/